# Java - Use PriorityQueue sort list but have empty list

Tags: java, priority-queue

This is my solution for leetcode 759. Employee Free Time, but it has index out of boundary issue that i don't understand.

I got "index 0 out of bounds for length 0" exception.

```
public List<Interval> employeeFreeTime(List<List<Interval>> schedule) {
    PriorityQueue<List<Interval>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> {
        System.out.println("b start " + b.get(0).start + "  end " + b.get(0).end);
        System.out.println("a start " + a.get(0).start + "  end " + a.get(0).end);
        Interval first = a.get(0);
        Interval second = b.get(0);
        int diff = first.start - second.start;
        if (diff == 0) return second.end - first.end;
        return diff;
    });
    for (List<Interval> s: schedule) pq.add(s);
    
    List<Interval> rst = new ArrayList<>();
    int start = pq.peek().get(0).start, end = pq.peek().get(0).end;
    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        List<Interval> list = pq.poll();
        Interval currt = list.remove(0);
        if (start <= currt.end) end = Math.max(end, currt.end);
        else {
            Interval freeTime = new Interval(end, currt.start);
            rst.add(freeTime);
            start = currt.start;
            end = currt.end;
        }
        pq.add(list);
    }
    return rst;
}
```

The test case i used is '[[[1,2]],[[1,3]],[[4,10]]]' and this is the output:

```
b start 1  end 2
a start 1  end 3
b start 1  end 3
a start 4  end 10
b start 1  end 2
a start 4  end 10
b start 1  end 2
```

I only have 3 lists and based on the output, it looks like it has compared all lists. Why does PriorityQueue compare [1,2] again with an empty list?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are polling from pq and removing the 0th element.

```
List<Interval> list = pq.poll();
Interval currt = list.remove(0); //here
```

you again adding this very same list to pq.

```
pq.add(list);
```

so when adding to pq, pq's comparator kicks in and see a list with 0th element removed.

thats why its throwing error.